# Deleting a point in METAFONT

Tags: metafont

In METAFONT, run interactively, is it possible to give a new value to a point variable?

If you just try to equate a point to a new point, the equation will be inconsistent with other equations.  If you try to assign a new value, MF says that `:=` is ''improper''.  And you can't wipe out z5 by `pair z5;` without taking all the other points with you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In MetaFont, `z5` etc. is just a shorthand for `(x5,y5)`. Now `(x5,y5):=(...)` wouldn't be allowed, so `z5:=(...)` isn't either.

To assign a new value, you can change both parts separably:
To reset `z5` to it's initial set and allow new assignments, write

```
x5:=whatever; y5:=whatever;
```

Then `z5=(3,4)` etc. works again.